# How to update Logistic Regression Model?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, machine-learning-model

I have trained a logistic regression model. Now I have to update(partial fit) the model with new set of training data. Is it possible ?

Comment: Some of **Sklearn** estimators implements `partial_fit` method. More [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You **cannot** use `partial_fit` on `LogisticRegression`.

But you can:

- use `warm_start=True`, which reuse the solution of the previous call to fit as initialization, to speed up convergence.
- use `SGDClassifier` with `loss='log'` which is equivalent to `LogisticRegression`, and which supports `partial_fit`.

Note the difference between `partial_fit` and `warm_start`. Both methods starts from the previous model and update it, but `partial_fit` updates only slightly the model, while `warm_start` goes all the way to convergence on the new training data, forgetting the previous model. `warm_start` is only used to speed up convergence.

See also [the glossary](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/glossary.html#term-warm-start):

> **`warm_start`**
>
> When fitting an estimator repeatedly on the same dataset, but for multiple parameter values (such as to find the value maximizing performance as in grid search), it may be possible to reuse aspects of the model learnt from the previous parameter value, saving time. When `warm_start` is true, the existing fitted model attributes an are used to initialise the new model in a subsequent call to `fit`.
>
> Note that this is only applicable for some models and some parameters, and even some orders of parameter values. For example, `warm_start` may be used when building random forests to add more trees to the forest (increasing `n_estimators`) but not to reduce their number.
>
> `partial_fit` also retains the model between calls, but differs: with `warm_start` the parameters change and the data is (more-or-less) constant across calls to fit; with `partial_fit`, the mini-batch of data changes and model parameters stay fixed.
>
> There are cases where you want to use `warm_start` to fit on different, but closely related data. For example, one may initially fit to a subset of the data, then fine-tune the parameter search on the full dataset. For classification, all data in a sequence of `warm_start` calls to `fit` must include samples from each class.

__

> **`partial_fit`**
>
> Facilitates fitting an estimator in an online fashion. Unlike `fit`, repeatedly calling `partial_fit` does not clear the model, but updates it with respect to the data provided. The portion of data provided to `partial_fit` may be called a mini-batch. Each mini-batch must be of consistent shape, etc.
>
> `partial_fit` may also be used for out-of-core learning, although usually limited to the case where learning can be performed online, i.e. the model is usable after each partial_fit and there is no separate processing needed to finalize the model. `cluster.Birch` introduces the convention that calling `partial_fit(X)` will produce a model that is not finalized, but the model can be finalized by calling `partial_fit()` i.e. without passing a further mini-batch.
>
> Generally, estimator parameters should not be modified between calls to `partial_fit`, although `partial_fit` should validate them as well as the new mini-batch of data. In contrast, `warm_start` is used to repeatedly fit the same estimator with the same data but varying parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, currently I'm using SGD classifier but the problem with this classifier is giving me different accuracy level every time for a same data set

Comment: This is due to the stochastic solver of `SGDClassifier`. To get a deterministic behavior, you can put an integer in the `random_state` parameter.